# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory error with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Hello i have been trying to learn machine learning from sentdex tutorial but ever time i try to compile that prgram i recieve this error: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'training_data.npy'`. I have searched the internet but found no clues. Here is my foled structure:

[image: structure]

Here is my code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
from random import shuffle
train_data=np.load('training_data.npy')
df=pd.DataFrame(train_data)
print(df.head())
print(Counter(df[1].apply(str)))
```

Comment: How do you execute the script? Do you run it from the folder where ``training_data.npy`` is located?

Comment: Yes, and i run it with the vs code coderunner extension

Comment: I faced the same issue in PyCharm. It happened after I moved the files to a different directory and ran the program. The solution was to delete the existing Run Configuration and create a new one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to your question is knowing what you don't know.
If you script can't find the file, most likely the script isn't running in the directory you think it's running.

To verify this, you could print your current directory in python and see where your script think it is.

```
import os
print(os.path.abspath("."))
```

Should print your current path.

From there you can either configure your code runner extension to start from the correct path or give your script an absolute path (starting from your computer's root folder, on windows it would be something like C:\Path\To\My\File) to open your file.

Comment: This part bears repeating: _If you script can't find the file, most likely the script isn't running in the directory you think it's running._ In my case, I had moved things around in the meantime and the directory the script was started in no longer existed. On Linux, of course, because Windows won't let you do that.

Comment: you could also do: os.getcwd() to get your current directory (current path)